# Is it possible to pull just one file in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I am working on a Git branch that has some broken tests, and I would like to pull (merge changes, not just overwrite) these tests from another branch where they are already fixed.

I know I can do

```
git pull origin that_other_branch
```

but this will attempt to merge lots of other files, for that I am not yet ready.

Is it possible to pull and merge only the specified file (and not everything) from that another branch?

This is not a duplicate of *[Git pull request for just one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421552/git-pull-request-for-just-one-file)* as all answers to that question are how to revert the locally changed file to the repository version, without changing any branches.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can fetch and then check out only one file in this way:

```
git fetch
git checkout -m <revision> <yourfilepath>
git add <yourfilepath>
git commit
```

**Regarding the `git checkout` command:**

- `<revision>` -- a branch name, i.e. `origin/master`
- `<yourfilepath>` does not include the repository name (that you can get from clicking `copy path` button on a file page on GitHub), i.e. `README.md`

Comment: The hash codes required by -m switch can be printed with git branch -v . Awesome!

Comment: Excellent. This has helped me on more than one occasion. To clarify, the -m flag seems to be happy with the hash of the commit from which you want to pull your single file.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Though, I ran git log on my remote branch to find the reversion: e.g. $ git log remotes/origin/master

Comment: you can get the latest remote hash from `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: Git automatically adds the file that is being checked out to the index (in the version that I use: `1.9.4.msysgit.1`). So, the third step is not needed but it doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Is it possible to pull specific file without pulling other files ?

Comment: @aleroot what does <revision> stands for?

Comment: This just overwrites the file, doesn't merge. May be it used to work before but dosn't work now

Comment: @wrangler the solution work as expected and solve the problem of the OP since he has accepted the answer... If you have other requirements than the OP then it would be better to ask a specific question instead of downvoting and bad commenting an accepted answer ...

Answer (score 266):

Here is a slightly easier method I just came up with when researching this:

```
git fetch {remote}
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- {file}
```

Comment: fatal: invalid reference: FETCH_HEAD

Comment: This answer possibly lacks a working example. It is unclear if one needs to commit next.

Comment: @Chris do we need {remote} if we are already in Branch? If yes, why?

Comment: Not the same as pull, which will attempt a merge, which is why we want to use pull.

Answer (score 57):

```
git checkout master -- myplugin.js
```

> master = branch name
>
> myplugin.js = file name

Comment: and is there a way to revert back?

Comment: don't forget to 'git pull' before ;)

Answer (score 40):

@Mawardy's answer worked for me, but my changes were on the remote so I had to specify the origin

```
git checkout origin/master -- {filename}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, especially if the file in question contains binary data or is stored with git LFS. Helped me with a merge conflict!

Answer (score 6):

In order to overwrite the local file with the file from some other repo or branch, the command is...

```
git checkout remoteName/branchName filePath
```

Here is an example I previously used...

```
git checkout origin/master package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is the process:

```
# Navigate to a directory and initiate a local repository
git init        

# Add remote repository to be tracked for changes:   
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository_name.git

# Track all changes made on above remote repository
# This will show files on remote repository not available on local repository
git fetch

# Add file present in staging area for checkout
git check origin/master -m /path/to/file
# NOTE: /path/to/file is a relative path from repository_name
git add /path/to/file

# Verify track of file(s) being committed to local repository
git status

# Commit to local repository
git commit -m "commit message"

# You may perform a final check of the staging area again with git status
```

Comment: I missed the git checkout line because it's hidden between comments.  Also, this says "git check" rather than "git checkout".

Answer (score 0):

To pull a specific file from a Git repository, you can use the `git checkout` command with the path to the file. Here's the syntax:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <file-path>
```

Replace `<commit>` with the commit hash, branch name, or tag name that contains the desired version of the file. Replace `<file-path>` with the path to the specific file you want to pull.

Here's an example to illustrate the usage:

```bash
git checkout main -- path/to/file.txt
```

In this example, it pulls the file named `file.txt` from the `main` branch.

If you want to update your local repository to the latest version of the file on the remote repository, you can run the `git pull` command after checking out the specific file:

```bash
git pull origin main
```

Replace `origin` with the appropriate remote name and `main` with the branch name you want to pull updates from.

Note: If you have any uncommitted changes in your local repository, it's recommended to stash or commit them before performing the checkout operation to avoid conflicts.