# Update a single file from git

Tags: git

I would like to update a specific file in a repository that I use.

Basically I have repo X, which has N files.

For one test, I need to have the latest and greatest of a specific file, since my application is already loaded, I can't just download the whole project again.

Is there a way to tell git to get from the repo, the latest and greatest version of just a specific file, without sync the whole repo/project?

I see that many uses the archive option of git, which to me seems a bit an overkill...I need to send a command to archive, and then another to unarchive on my local directory; while I would like that git would simply look at the repo, and if there are changes only to that specific file, it will update it.

How do you do that? I can't see in Git manual a way to specify a file in the repo. I use regular git from console, no UI nor Github.

Comment: This is a duplicate or near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230838/git-is-it-possible-to-pull-just-for-one-file

Comment: It looks similar, but in my question I simply need to checkout the file from the repository.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First make sure you have the latest and greatest version available in your local git repo:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then retrieve the one specific file you're looking for

```
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/the/file
```

The `--` tells `git` that all other arguments are files, not parameters.

Comment: Thanks Arjan; I fetch often so I just need the git command for the checkout