# Download a specific file from GIT repo on CodePlex

Tags: c#, git, codeplex

I'm trying to implement a simple auto-update service for our WinForms application which is hosted in GIT on CodePlex.
My auto-updater needs a json file which holds the latest version number and installer url.
I've put this file on another webserver and my updated could easily read the file.

To make our life not more complicated than necessary I want to save this file in GIT as well.
Using the CodePlex browser the url is https://mapwindow5.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/SolutionItems/mw5-update.json

I had hoped the url is something like https://git01.codeplex.com/mapwindow5/src/SolutionItems/mw5-update.json
But it isn't ;(

Does anybody have experience with getting just 1 file from CodePlex GIT?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching then checking out just the file you need as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230838/git-is-it-possible-to-pull-just-for-one-file):

```
git fetch
git checkout -m <revision> <yourfilepath>
git add <yourfilepath>
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the auto-updater will run on the clients and I don't want to introduce a GIT dependency.