# Is there a way to sync only specific directories (and their subdirectories) between two git repositories ? If yes, how?

Tags: git, synchronization, partial

I have two GIT repositories and I would like to be able to sync only some of the directories (and their subdirectories) at a time.

Let's say I have two repositories containing the same directories tree as they started from a single base:

repo1/.git
repo1/A/file1
repo1/A/a/file2
repo1/B/file3
repo1/B/b/file4

repo2/.git
repo2/A/file1
repo2/A/a/file2
repo2/B/file3
repo2/B/b/file4

git pull from repo1 to repo2 would bring the changes in all the files.
Instead of that, I would like for example to sync only the files below the A directory (file1 and file2) from repo1 into repo2 without syncing the files below the B directory (file3 and file4). Files below the B directory could be still be synced later on.

Is this somehow possible?
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. I looked at the sparse checkout feature but I don't understand whether it can be used for that purpose.

Comment: We need a good description what **exactly** you want to do. Also, a few examples what have you tried so far. See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for further details.

Anyway, [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) can do this.

Comment: Hi Tamas, thanks for your comments. I edited the question. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: Yes, cool, thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you!
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hi Tamas, do you have an answer for that question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867127/how-to-diff-with-git-a-subtree-within-a-bigger-repo-and-the-repo-it-originates-f
?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this boils down to fetching the other repo, then checking out the specific files only. Something like this must do:

```
git fetch repo2
git checkout -m FETCH_HEAD A/file1 A/file2
git add A/file1 A/file2
git commit
```

You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16230838/187808).

Comment: Thanks Tamas. Would that merge changes in the files or only overwrite them? Actually I need a merge (like what happens in a pull).

Comment: ok great, I will test this out.
Do you have also a solution without naming the files explicitely and that will take care as well of removing files that were removed in the other repo?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I have such command right away. You can try though to checkout the directory only: `git checkout -m FETCH_HEAD A`

Comment: Thank you! Running git checkout on a directory is supposed to be recursive?