# Downloading a specific file from Repository (Like Bit bucket) using Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, bitbucket

I want to download a specific file ("Web/Externals/Settings.txt") in a folder(which is not having git) from my bit bucket repository "TestRepository" with branch name "TestBranch".

Please suggest

**Editing with my exact Problem:**

My Powershell clode:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri "https://{CompanyRepoUrl}/projects/{PojectName}/repos/{RepoName}/browse/{SpecificFilePath}?at=refs/heads/{BranchName}&raw" -OutFile "D:\Checkout1\AppSettings.config"
```

Output File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><title>Log in - Bitbucket</title><script>
window.WRM=window.WRM||{};window.WRM._unparsedData=window.WRM._unparsedData||{};window.WRM._unparsedErrors=window.WRM._unparsedErrors||{};
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-plugin:context-path.context-path"]="\u0022\u0022";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.feature-wrm-data:nps.survey.inline.dialog.data"]="true";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.feature-wrm-data:nps.experiment.enabled.by.sen.data"]="false";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.analytics.analytics-client:policy-update-init.policy-update-data-provider"]="false";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.analytics.analytics-client:programmatic-analytics-init.programmatic-analytics-data-provider"]="false";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.feature-wrm-data:user.time.zone.onboarding.data"]="true";
if(window.WRM._dataArrived)window.WRM._dataArrived();</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/6fc27be4ccefd02668bbfc7707f252e7-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/ae1be24ea8754179495e60ec2eaba772/_/download/contextbatch/css/_super/batch.css" data-wrm-key="_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/962c32d4bcd07cffe83c89c4987985f1-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/ea28cfaf2acbe7b82e7be0a0260044b0/_/download/contextbatch/css/bitbucket.page.login,-_super/batch.css" data-wrm-key="bitbucket.page.login,-_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/43d0d6b83940f27a9738c7a1fd4ab66f-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/b003941031bbabfa1020a97617ac2fb8/_/download/contextbatch/css/bitbucket.layout.focused,bitbucket.layout.base,atl.general,-_super/batch.css?analytics-enabled=true&amp;analytics-uploadable=true&amp;nps-acknowledged=true&amp;nps-enabled=true&amp;supportedApplication=true" data-wrm-key="bitbucket.layout.focused,bitbucket.layout.base,atl.general,-_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/cc6c46d7d3fcbbb11de60545692c4308-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/ae1be24ea8754179495e60ec2eaba772/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super/batch.js?locale=en-US" data-wrm-key="_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" data-initially-rendered></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/425a942c33d855b433ca42cd757fbeeb-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/ea28cfaf2acbe7b82e7be0a0260044b0/_/download/contextbatch/js/bitbucket.page.login,-_super/batch.js?locale=en-US" data-wrm-key="bitbucket.page.login,-_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" data-initially-rendered></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/284b087232caf6957d24ceef210fa0dc-CDN/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/b003941031bbabfa1020a97617ac2fb8/_/download/contextbatch/js/bitbucket.layout.focused,bitbucket.layout.base,atl.general,-_super/batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&amp;analytics-uploadable=true&amp;locale=en-US&amp;nps-acknowledged=true&amp;nps-enabled=true&amp;supportedApplication=true" data-wrm-key="bitbucket.layout.focused,bitbucket.layout.base,atl.general,-_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" data-initially-rendered></script>
<meta name="application-name" content="Bitbucket"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/s/1989337664/f3f46d5/1/1.0/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-web:favicon/favicon.ico" /><link rel="search" href="https://{CompanyRepoUrl}/plugins/servlet/opensearch-descriptor" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Bitbucket code search" /></head><body class="aui-page-focused aui-page-focused-small aui-page-size-small bitbucket-theme user-login"><ul id="assistive-skip-links" class="assistive"><li><a href="#content">Skip to content</a></li></ul><div id="page"><!-- start #header --><header id="header" role="banner"><section class="notifications"></section><nav class="aui-header aui-dropdown2-trigger-group" role="navigation"><div class="aui-header-inner"><div class="aui-header-before"><a class=" aui-dropdown2-trigger app-switcher-trigger" aria-controls="app-switcher" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" data-aui-trigger href="#app-switcher"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-appswitcher">Linked Applications</span></a><div id="app-switcher" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" data-is-switcher="true" data-environment="{&quot;isUserAdmin&quot;:false,&quot;isAppSuggestionAvailable&quot;:false,&quot;isSiteAdminUser&quot;:false}"><div role="application"><div class="app-switcher-loading">Loading&hellip;</div></div></div></div><div class="aui-header-primary"><h1 id="logo" class="aui-header-logo aui-header-logo-bitbucket"><a href="https://{CompanyRepoUrl}" class="stash"><span class="aui-header-logo-device">Bitbucket</span></a></h1><meta name="stp-license-product-name" content="Bitbucket"/> <meta name="stp-license-days-to-expiry" content="265"/> <meta name="stp-license-is-admin" content="false"/> <meta name="stp-license-should-keep-banner-hidden" content="true"/><ul class="aui-nav"></ul></div><div class="aui-header-secondary"><ul class="aui-nav"><li class=" help-link"title="Help"><a class=" aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless" aria-controls="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments-help-menu" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" data-aui-trigger><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help">Help</span><span class="icon aui-icon-dropdown"></span></a><div id="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments-help-menu" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default" role="menu" aria-hidden="true"><div role="application"><div class="aui-dropdown2-section help-items-section"><ul class="aui-list-truncate" role="presentation"><li role="presentation"><a href="http://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/docs-0411/Bitbucket+Server+Documentation+Home?utm_campaign=in-app-help&amp;amp;utm_medium=in-app-help&amp;amp;utm_source=stash" title="Go to the online documentation for Bitbucket" data-web-item-key="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments:general-help">Online help</a></li><li role="presentation"><a href="https://www.atlassian.com/git?utm_campaign=learn-git&amp;utm_medium=in-app-help&amp;utm_source=stash" title="Learn about Git commands &amp; workflows" data-web-item-key="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments:learn-git">Learn Git</a></li><li role="presentation"><a href="/getting-started" class="getting-started-page-link" title="Overview of Bitbucket features" data-web-item-key="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments:getting-started-page-help-link">Welcome to Bitbucket</a></li><li role="presentation"><a href="/#" class="keyboard-shortcut-link" title="Discover keyboard shortcuts in Bitbucket" data-web-item-key="com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-server-web-fragments:keyboard-shortcuts-help-link">Keyboard shortcuts</a></li></ul></div></div></div></li></ul></div></div> <!-- End .aui-header-inner --></nav> <!-- End .aui-header --></header><!-- End #header --><!-- Start #content --><section id="content" role="main" tabindex="-1" data-timezone="0" ><div class="aui-page-panel content-body"><div class="aui-page-panel-inner"><section class="aui-page-panel-content"><h2>Log in</h2><form class="aui top-label prevent-double-submit " action="/j_atl_security_check" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div class="field-group"><label for="j_username" >Username</label><input class="text long-field" type="text" id="j_username"  name="j_username"  autofocus accesskey="u"/></div><div class="field-group"><label for="j_password" >Password</label><input class="text long-field" type="password" id="j_password"  name="j_password"  accesskey="p"/></div><div class="aui-group"><fieldset class="group checkbox"><div class="checkbox"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="_atl_remember_me"  name="_atl_remember_me"  checked="checked"  accesskey="r"/><label for="_atl_remember_me" >Keep me logged in</label></div></fieldset></div><div class="aui-group"><input name="next" type="hidden" value="/projects/{ProjectName}/repos/{RepoName}/browse/{FilePath}?at=refs/heads/release/v8.6.0.0&amp;raw"/><input class="aui-button aui-button-primary" type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit"  value="Log in" accesskey="s"/><a id="forgot" class="aui-button aui-button-link"  name="forgot" href="/passwordreset" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">Unable to access your account?</a></div></form></section><!-- .aui-page-panel-content --></div><!-- .aui-page-panel-inner --></div><!-- .aui-page-panel --></section><!-- End #content --><!-- Start #footer --><footer id="footer" role="contentinfo"><section class="notifications"></section><section class="footer-body"><ul><li data-key="footer.license.message">Git repository management for enterprise teams powered by <a href="http://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/">Atlassian Bitbucket</a></li></ul><ul><li>Atlassian Bitbucket <span title="f3f46d5e0c4ae2874e5c7dab7bea40ffa6d278bc" id="product-version" data-commitid="f3f46d5e0c4ae2874e5c7dab7bea40ffa6d278bc" data-system-build-number="f3f46d5"> v4.11.1</span></li><li data-key="footer.links.documentation"><a href="http://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/docs-0411/Bitbucket+Server+Documentation+Home?utm_campaign=in-app-help&amp;utm_medium=in-app-help&amp;utm_source=stash" target="_blank">Documentation</a></li><li data-key="footer.links.contact.support"><a href="https://support.atlassian.com/secure/SENVerification.jspa?issuetype=1&pid=10740" target="_blank">Contact Support</a></li><li data-key="footer.links.jac"><a href="https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV" target="_blank">Request a feature</a></li><li data-key="footer.links.about"><a href="/about">About</a></li><li data-key="footer.links.contact.atlassian"><a href="http://www.atlassian.com/company/contact/" target="_blank">Contact Atlassian</a></li></ul><div id="footer-logo"><a href="http://www.atlassian.com/" target="_blank">Atlassian</a></div></section></footer><!-- End #footer --></div><script>require('bitbucket/internal/layout/base').onReady(null, "Bitbucket" ); require('bitbucket/internal/widget/keyboard-shortcuts').onReady();</script><script type="text/javascript">require('bitbucket/internal/page/login').onReady();</script></body></html>
```

How to get the exact file this is html related to the login page of the RepoUrl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pull just one file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230838/is-it-possible-to-pull-just-one-file-in-git)

Comment: Hi @Liam, I'm able to download the file using c#. If it is not possible even from c# it will not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function CheckOutDevFile($userName, $password, $CheckOutFilePath, $RepoUrl){
    $userNamePaswords = "$($userName):$($password)"
    $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($userNamePaswords))
    $authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials"
    $Headers = @{ Authorization = $authorization }

    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers $RepoUrl -OutFile $CheckOutFilePath
}


$userName = 'Your User name'
$password = 'Your password'
$CheckOutFilePath = 'Your out put location with file name'
$RepoUrl = 'https://{CompanyRepoUrl}/projects/{PojectName}/repos/{RepoName}/raw/{SpecificFilePath}?at=refs/heads/{BranchName}'

CheckOutDevFile $userName $password $CheckOutFilePath $RepoUrl
```

Comment: In my case, there is an issue in "$RepoUrl". So I changed it as below and works for me
"https://bitbucket.org/{UserName}/{RepoName}/raw/HEAD/{fileName}"