# How to update individual page in github project?

Tags: git, github, heroku

I have already published a project on the `heroku` now I want to update my individual page with individual commit.

when I try by this way:

```
git fetch
git checkout -m <revision> <yourfilepath>
git add <yourfilepath>
git commit
```

But, when I go on the `git checkout -m <revision> <filepath>` then my updated value or data has deleted.

I had did like this: `git checkout -m master .\client\src\pages\About.js`

I have followed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230838/is-it-possible-to-pull-just-one-file-in-git) but still can't solved my problem

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Anyone find my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309), I would advice to use instead [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), which only deals with files.
Example, to [get just one file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364223/6309), and add it to the index, in one command:

```
 git restore --source <revision> --staged --worktree -- <yourfilepath>
```